# jquery click append and remove append second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a append menu on click div. But i have one question here. How can i remove appended elements after second click. Anyone can help me in this regard ?

This is the [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/VarRrm) page from *codepen.io*

Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("body").on("click", ".menu-button", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $(".menu-container").append('<div class="button"></div><div class="rebackbar"></div><div class="abc" id="myDiv"></div><div class="lBrgF"><div class="card"><span class="three-quarters-loader">Loading&#8230; </span></div></div>');
   });

});
```

Comment: why dont you use toggle jquery http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Try this?http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOPwvw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like toggling the element instead of adding it would be better, but you could just put a check

```
var childNodes = $(".menu-container").children();
if (childNodes.length) {
    childNodes.remove();
} else {
    $(".menu-container").append("...");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can i ask you one more question relating my question. Your code is clean and understandable but how can i remove after other area append ? Like $("body").on("click", function(){});

Comment: `$("body").on("click", function(evt){
    if ( !$(evt.target).closest(".menu-container").length) {
        $(".menu-container").children().remove();
    }
});`

Comment: the append is not worked now can you check it for me [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/VarRrm)

Comment: if ( !$(evt.target).closest(".menu-container").length && !$(".menu-button").is(evt.target)) {

Answer (score 1):

Append the content only if the content not exist.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("body").on("click", ".menu-button", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (!$('.button').length) {
         $(".menu-container").append('<div class="button"></div><div class="rebackbar"></div><div class="abc" id="myDiv"></div><div class="lBrgF"><div class="card"><span class="three-quarters-loader">Loading&#8230; </span></div></div>');
      } else {
         $(".menu-container").html(''); // Empty after 
      }
   });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution
I've called the `dblclick` event to empty the contents of the `menu-container`.This empties the entire div.Incase you want to remove the last child, you can find the length and remove the last one that way.

```
$("body").on("dblclick", ".menu-button", function(event){
         $(".menu-container").empty();
     });
```

**[Working Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOPwvw)**

Answer (score 1):

By no means the most elegant solution but probably the easiest:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("body").on("click", ".menu-button", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      if($('.menu-container').html().length > 0) {
         $(".menu-container").html(null)
      }
      else {
         $(".menu-container").html('<div class="button"></div><div class="rebackbar"></div><div class="abc" id="myDiv"></div><div class="lBrgF"><div class="card"><span class="three-quarters-loader">Loading&#8230; </span></div></div>');
      }
   });

});
```